# Failing to get fields of an object

Tags: c#

Simple c# console application to check how to get fields of an unknown object.

```
public class A
{
    public int id;
    public string name;
    public string desc;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A a = new A();
        getProp(a);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static object getProp(object o)
    {
        Type type = o.GetType();
        PropertyInfo[] pros = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

        //Do Something
        return null;
    }
}
```

I am not getting any fields. `pros` has no value inside it. I have to get the field names of the `object o`.

Comment: Those are not properties, they are fields.

Comment: You have *fields*, not properties.  Properties would look like `public int id { get; set; }` (for an automatic property).

Comment: ok. my mistake. Is there any way to get fields?

Comment: use `type.GetFields`.

Comment: Why is this question downvoted? What "rules" does it break?

Comment: @AndreiV I did not down vote but.. I clearly see lack of research

Comment: Lack of research I can understand... Maybe he did not know the difference between a field and a property. If one does not know such details, how can one search for a solution?

Comment: By the way, fields should be private.  If you need to expose them to other classes, use a property.

Answer (score 1):

The members which you're trying to fetch are not ***properties***, but ***fields***. Try the following:

```
var fields = typeof(A).GetFields();
```

Or:

```
static FieldInfo[] GetFields(object o)
{
    Type type = o.GetType();
    FieldInfo[] fields = type.GetFields();
    
    return fields;
}
```

And in order to grab the object's fields values:

```
var fields = GetFields(obj);
foreach(var field in fields)
{
  Console.WriteLine(field.GetValue(obj));
}
```

From MSDN:

> **Type.GetFields Method**
>
> Returns all the public fields of the current Type.

Comment: @TaW Yes.. should not be a problem.